# where does 'apt-cache depends' collect the dependency information from?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I want to modify the dependencies of a debian package and I have made changes in its control file. But, the list of `apt-cache depends pkg_name` still displays the removed dependencies. So, where does the above command fetches the dependency list of a debian package from? Is it not from the control file?

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cache` data comes from lists within:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists
```

e.g:

```
grep -i "Package: wget$" -A10 /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_zesty_main_binary-amd64_Packages
```

However as you know, the deb package's meta-data, contains a list of dependencies too.

So if you want to see what a `deb` file thinks of its own dependecies run:

```
dpkg -I package-name.deb | grep -i depends
```

Comment: despite changing the dependency list in the file from the directory you have mentioned still displays the removed dependencies when 'apt-cache depends' is run. Any ideas?

Comment: Not much, there is a binary file `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin ` which apt create it with these lists for doing faster queries, try removing that, see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting a clear picture what you are trying to do however I am trying to answer  your question 

**Where does 'apt-cache depends' collect the dependency information from?**

When you run `apt-get update`, it fetches all the packages metadata from repositories mentioned in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.

These metadata are  stored in two files

`/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`  
and 
`var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin`

`apt-cache` command uses these  two cache files to display the user's queries.

---

#### *How these files are Updated?*

`srcpkgcache.bin` includes  all informations you get from the internet
by deb and deb-src lines 
**These information are changed only on apt-get update**.

Where as `pkgcache.bin`  caches the information in `srcpkgcache.bin` and 
the informations extracted from the apt and dpkg status files. 
**These information change on every changes done by apt or dpkg.**