# Read full dpkg database state without dpkg program

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

From a Live USB, and without using the installed Ubuntu's programs like `dpkg`, `dpkg-query`, `dselect`, `aptitude`, `apt-get`, or any other (as they are all [broken `Illegal instruction`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083787/kernel-panic-at-boot-and-many-programs-segfault-core-dump)), how do I read the package lists that  `apt` reads, as a list in order to catalogue the installed packages, to reinstall later?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

[where is local package database?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1372833) is almost a perfect answer:

> `/var/lib/dpkg/status` is modified by dpkg if you change the state of a package, i.e. install it, remove it, mark it for some action, ...

- I don't want just to list "changed" packages, but also depended packages, the entire state of the system, etc. Is that contained by `dpkg/status`?

  - On another healthy system, that file has ~3800 `Package:` entries; on the target system it has 3600 `Package:` entries, and on the Live USB it has only 2000 entries. That sounds right except I worry it doesn't list *all* the packages.
- I am not looking for the downloaded `.deb` cache, nor the `cache` for `dpkg` / `apt` which holds temporary data files -- these do not give the full system state.
- [`/var/lib/apt/lists`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937927/where-is-the-information-from-apt-show-packagename-stored?rq=1) seems to contain a list of package sources and packages, which is almost perfect except a lot of parsing is involved in getting a list of package names from it. Is this the best option?

The file [`/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911785/where-does-apt-cache-depends-collect-the-dependency-information-from) exists but since it's a generated binary, I don't think copying it to a fresh install will be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dpkg.1.html):

> The other files listed below are in their default directories, see
>   option `--admindir` to see how to change locations of these files.
>
> - `/var/lib/dpkg/available` List of available packages.
> - `/var/lib/dpkg/status` Statuses of available packages.
>
>   This file contains information about whether a package is marked for
>     removing or not, whether it is installed or not, etc. See section
>     INFORMATION ABOUT PACKAGES for more info. The status file is backed up
>     daily in `/var/backups`. It can be useful if it's lost or corrupted due
>     to filesystems troubles.

You can quit worrying. If the package isn't in `status`, `dpkg` doesn't know about it. At all.

---

By the way, the "package lists" that apt is taking about is a different thing: those are the lists it downloaded from the sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, etc. and are in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. These contain information about packages in the repositories, and have nothing about the local system.

---

About your current problem, you can use the live system's `dpkg` to read that file, using the `--admindir` option mentioned above.